# How do I allow a user to only fetch their own data? Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I've already implemented Firebase in my app. I'm able to press a button and send the desired data to Firebase. I also set up a table view, so that the desired data is then added to the table view. However, when any user presses the butting to send data and update the table, all of the data is pulled, even from other users. It seems the entire database is being pulled, rather than the one specific to the user. I want a user to be able to get the hand drying options that they entered/saved based on their uid, not those of other users. I think it has something to do with this part of the code: let handDryLocations = ["id":key

I'm very new to all of this so any help would be very much appreciated. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class HandDrySaveViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var refHandrylocations: DatabaseReference!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var BestOption: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didGetNotification4(_:)), name: Notification.Name("text4"), object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didGetNotification5(_:)), name: Notification.Name("text5"), object: nil)
        
        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        
        refHandrylocations = Database.database().reference().child("users");
        
        refHandrylocations.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                self.handDryList.removeAll()
                
                for handDryOptions in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                    let handDryObject = handDryOptions.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let handDryLocation = handDryObject?["handrylocation"]
                    let handDryBest = handDryObject?["handdrybest"]
                    let handDryString = handDryObject?["handdryoption"]
                    let handDryId = handDryObject?["id"]
                    
                    let handDry = HandDryModel(id: handDryId as! String?, location: handDryLocation as! String?, best: handDryBest as! String?, options: handDryString as! String?)
                    
                    self.handDryList.append(handDry)
                }
                
                self.handDryTable.reloadData()
            }
        })
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func BacktoHDCalcButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "TowelVDryer")
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func addHandDryLocation(){
        let key = refHandrylocations.childByAutoId().key
        
        let handDryLocations = ["id":key,
                                "handrylocation": HandDryLocation.text! as String,
                                "handdrybest" : BestOption.text! as String,
                                "handdryoption" : HandDryOptionsString.text! as String
                                    ]
        refHandrylocations.child(key!).setValue(handDryLocations)
        
        OptionSavedMessage.text = "Location Saved"        
    }    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var HandDryOptionsString: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var HandDryLocation: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var OptionSavedMessage: UILabel!
    @IBAction func BackButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
    
    
    @objc func didGetNotification4(_ notification: Notification){
        let text = notification.object as! String?
        HandDryOptionsString.text = text
    }
    
    @objc func didGetNotification5(_ notification: Notification){
        let text = notification.object as! String?
        BestOption.text = text
    }
    
    @IBAction func SaveHandDryButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        addHandDryLocation()
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var handDryTable: UITableView!
    
    var handDryList = [HandDryModel]()
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return handDryList.count
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! HandDrySavedTableViewCell
        
        let handDry: HandDryModel
        
        handDry = handDryList[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.locationOfOption.text = handDry.location
        cell.bestOption.text = handDry.best
        cell.optionString.text = handDry.options
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I appreciate the help, but truthfully I don't know how to do that. I tried replacing the two lines of my code you pointed out with what you said and changing "id":key to "uid":key, but that didn't work. Would you mind walking me through it a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the data for all users here:

```
refHandrylocations = Database.database().reference().child("users");

refHandrylocations.observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
```

If you want to read the data for only specific users, you will have to change this code to specify what users to read the data for.

---

For example, if you've stored the information for each user using their UID as the key, you can read only that key with:

```
refHandrylocations = Database.database().reference().child("users");
var uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid; // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

refHandrylocations.child(uid ).observe(DataEventType.value, with:{(snapshot) in
    let handDryObject = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    let handDryLocation = snapshot?["handrylocation"]
    let handDryBest = snapshot?["handdrybest"]
    let handDryString = snapshot?["handdryoption"]
    let handDryId = snapshot?["id"]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing. I'm sure its not perfect to a pro, but it gets the job done for me.

```
guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

ref!.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Quotes").childByAutoId().setValue(quotesLabel.text!)
```